# How do I cut word and value from cut command field value?

Tags: text-processing, grep, cut

This is the line format of the my file:

```
29.101.26.176 [11/Oct/2017:10:21:41 /pmk/clk?aff_id=5863&off_id=85635&trans_id=easoli4ddq8sssdf&prm2=23398_27530&device_id=864792012331091090 "Mozilla/5.0 Mobile
```

I need to cut `aff_id=5863` and `off_id=85635` and `trans_id=easoli4ddq8sssdf`.

I can only cut the specific field from `cut` command not the word inside the field. How can I separate the given word?

Comment: do you need to extract them or modify the line by deleting them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short **grep** approach:

```
grep -Eo '([ao]ff|trans)_id=[^&]+' file
```

The output:

```
aff_id=5863
off_id=85635
trans_id=easoli4ddq8sssdf
```

**----------**

Or **awk** solution for fixed item order:

```
awk -F'[?&]' '{ printf "%s %s %s\n",$2,$3,$4 }' file
```

The output:

```
aff_id=5863 off_id=85635 trans_id=easoli4ddq8sssdf
```

Answer (score 1):

Use GNU `sed` to remove matched patterns:

```
sed -E 's#([ao]ff|trans)_id=[^&]*&##g' infile
```

If you want get those string value.

```
sed 's#.*\(aff_id=[^&]\).*\(off_id=[^&]\+\).*\(trans_id=[^&]\+\).*#\1 \2 \3#' infile
aff_id=5863 off_id=85635 trans_id=easoli4ddq8sssdf
```